# How to extract the total number of commit pages for a github repository

Tags: bash, shell, github, github-api, git-bash

I'm setting up an script for exporting all commits and pull requests for a bigger list of github repositories (about 4000).

After the basic idea of the script works i need a way to loop through all pages of commits for a repository.

I found out that i can export 100 commits per page. For some repos there is some more commits (like 8000) so that would be 80 pages i need to loop through.

I can't find a way to extract the number of pages from the github api.

What i've done so far is set up the script that it loops through all commits and exports them to a txt / csv file.

What i need to do is to know the total number of pages before i start looping through the commits of a repo.

This here gives me the number of pages in a way that i can't use it.

```
curl -u "user:password" -I https://api.github.com/repos/0chain/rocksdb/commits?per_page=100
```

RESULT:

> Link: https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=2; rel="next", https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=75; rel="last"

I need the value 75 (or any other value from other repos) to be used as a variable in a loop.

Like so:

```
repolist=`cat repolist.txt`
repolistarray=($(echo $repolist))
repolength=$(echo "${#repolistarray[@]}")

for (( i = 0; i <= $repolength; i++ )); do
    #here i need to extract the pagenumber
    pagenumber=$(curl -u "user:password" -I https://api.github.com/repos/$(echo "${repolistarray[i]}")/commits?per_page=100)

    for (( n = 1; n <= $pagenumber; n++ )); do
        curl -u "user:password" -s https://api.github.com/repos/$(echo "${repolistarray[i]}")/commits?per_page=100&page$(echo "$n") >committest.txt
    done
done

done
```

How can I get the "75" or any other result out of this

> Link: https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=2; rel="next", https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=75; rel="last"

to be used as "n"?

Comment: You don't need that number. Get the first page and while there's a "next" link, follow it, loop until the end, where the "next" link is empty.

Comment: @Poshi i'm quite new to all of that. Do you have any hint on how to follow the "next" link under given circumstances? I don't need a full solution just an idea on how to.

Thank you for your reply

Comment: Why use github at all? It would be far easier to use git. Git itself is very scriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something along the lines of what @Poshi commented: loop indefinitely requesting the next page until you hit an empty page, then break out of the inner loop, moving on to the next repo.

```
# this is the contents of a page past the last real page:
emptypage='[

]'

# here's a simpler way to iterate over each repo than using a bash array
cat repolist.txt | while read -d' ' repo; do

  # loop indefinitely
  page=0
  while true; do
    page=$((page + 1))

    # minor improvement: use a variable, not a file.
    # also, you don't need to echo variables, just use them
    result=$(curl -u "user:password" -s \ 
      "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/commits?per_page=100&page=$n")

    # if the result is empty, break out of the inner loop
    [ "$result" = "$emptypage" ] && break

    echo "$result" > committest.txt
    # note that > overwrites (whereas >> appends),
    # so committest.txt will be overwritten with each new page.
    #
    # in the final version, you probably want to process the results here,
    # and then
    #
    #       echo "$processed_results"
    #     done > repo1.txt
    #   done
    #
    # to ouput once per repo, or
    #
    #       echo "$processed_results"
    #     done
    #   done > all_results.txt
    #
    # to output all results to a single file

  done
done
```

Comment: Hey webb,

first of all thank you for your really good comment. I got all of your points and the comments inside the code are really helpful.

The only thing is that it won't output any file if i use it like you posted it. I got the feeling that there might be something wrong with the TXT file i have.

It's a string seperated by breaks.

like so:
```
Zolmeister/treemix
Zolmeister/truffle-core
Zolmeister/Tuxman
Zolmeister/udio
Zolmeister/UltimateICOCalendar
Zolmeister/varnish-dashboard
```

When i execute the script it starts but doesn't really output anything

Comment: OK - short debug update so far. Something is going wrong with the for loop. Everything else works fantastic. Somehow its not adding the pages like it should.

Comment: another short debug update: somehow it is not taking the "true" value in the for loop

Comment: Hey there, so my quick and dirty solution for this in the end was to just replace 
"true" with "n<=5000"
since none of the repositorys has more than 5000*100=500000 commits.

But still, if you have the "correct" solution for me i'd be really thankful.

Comment: hi adonis. as you point out, `for ((...;true;...))` doesn't work, so i replaced it with a while loop that does, and also changed the `while read` to `while read -d' '` to break input data on spaces (or newlines) instead of only newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the method you ask for is not the most common one, usually it is done by fetching pages until no more data is available. But to answer your specific question, we must parse the line that contains the information. A quick and dirty way to do this could be:

```
response="Link: https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=2; rel=\"next\", https://api.github.com/repositories/152923130/commits?per_page=100&page=75; rel=\"last\""

<<< "$response" cut -f2- -d: | # First, get the contents of "Link": everything after the first colon
tr "," $'\n' |      # Separate the different parts in different lines
grep 'rel="last"' | # Select the line with last page information
cut -f1 -d';' |     # Keep only the URL
tr "?&" $'\n' |     # Split URL and its parameters, one per line
grep -e "^page" |   # Select the "page" parameter
cut -f2 -d=         # Finally, extract the number we are interested in
```

There are some other ways to do this, with less commands, maybe simpler, but this one allows me to go step by step with the explanation. One of these other ways could be:

```
<<< "$response" sed 's/.*&page=\(.*\); rel="last".*/\1/'
```

This one makes some assumptions, like the `page` will always be the last parameter.

Comment: Hey Poshi,

thanks alot. I used webbs solution though because my code looks alot cleaner afterwards (who would've guessed)

I wrote down all of your notes though.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I know: that's the most common way to tackle this problem because it is easier and cleaner. That's what I told in my initial comment. Anyways, your question was a different one: how to extract the number you were looking for, so there's my answer :-)

Comment: could be a bit simpler tho:
`grep -o '[0-9]\+; rel="last"' <<<"$response" | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`

Comment: or `echo "$response" | perl -ne '/([0-9]+); rel="last"/; print "$1\n";'`

Answer (score 0):

The official [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli#github-cli) (`gh`) supports a `--paginate` flag that does the heavy lifting for you. Combined with `jq`, you can get the answers you're looking for.

This is simpler, and should be more robust than the other Bash solutions posted earlier.

#### Examples

Total number of commits in the last 90 days:

```bash
gh api --paginate \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
"/repos/sindresorhus/awesome/commits?since=$(date -I -v-90d)&per_page=100" |
jq length
```

Number of commits for the last 6 months, broken down by month, as CSV:

```bash
gh api --paginate \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
"/repos/sindresorhus/awesome/commits?since=$(date -I -v-6m)&per_page=100" |
jq -r 'map(. + {month: (.commit.committer.date[:7])}) |
group_by(.month)[] | [(.[0].month), length] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"2023-01",1
"2023-02",6
"2023-03",3
"2023-04",5
"2023-05",3
"2023-06",11
```